# add values in specific columns horizontally in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have created a dataframe from python pandas using a numpy array but i want to know how do i add values in specific columns horizontally not vertically

let's assume i have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
```

[image]

how can i add [1.2,3.5,2.2] to the second row of (-1,label) (-2,label) (0,label)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#if need set last 3 columns and index 1
df.loc[1, df.columns[-3:]] = [1.2,3.5,2.2]
```

Or [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
#if need set last 3 columns and second index
df.iloc[1, -3:] = [1.2,3.5,2.2]
```

Or:

```
#if need set columns by names
cols = [col1, col3, col5]
df.loc[1, cols] = [1.2,3.5,2.2]
```